# Machine Learning Model for Time Series Forecasting

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting

I am using Random Forest, SVM, and XGBoost models to nowcast/forecast an economic time series variable. However, I would like to extend these models to optimize/customize them for time series forecasting. Does anybody have experience in a similar situation, or is there a paper I could review?

Any recommendations are greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can check the Pycaret python package (or Caret if you work in R). https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-forecasting-with-pycaret-regression-module-237b703a0c63#:~:text=PyCaret%20is%20an%20alternate%20low,code%20with%20few%20lines%20only.&text=Whether%20it's%20imputing%20missing%20values,PyCaret%20automates%20all%20of%20it.